# Pointer in C++ (syntax)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have some guesses I wish to confirm. I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me out.

When I declare a pointer in C++, for example

```
int *x = 5;
```

Does that mean that * is not for dereferencing, but just for declaration of the pointer; as a result, x is referring to the address of int x?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `x` is referring to the address of *some* int. For now, it points nowhere because it is not initialized, but you can point it at any `int` and it will take its address.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you haven't already, please feel free to check out [how to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/ask) and [what's on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost correct, `int *x` (that you can also write `int* x`) means that x is a pointer to an int... But there is not int liked to it yet

```
int *x = 5;
```

actually means that x is a pointer that is linked to **memory address** 5, which should contain an int. Since this address is probably not allocated by your program, this will likely fail.

You can try to do the following

```
int x = 5;
int *xAddr = &x;
*xAddr = 3;
```

Here we declared xAddr in the same way as you did, but telling it that it points to the address (that's the **`&`** character) of x;
By changing the value that xAddr points to to 3 (line 3, here we are dereferencing), we change the value of x to 3

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) is a nice tutorial to understand pointers better